# Is it safe to use \texorpdfstring from package hyperref, outside the sectioning commands?

Tags: sectioning, hyperref

I have several commands with some math that I use inside and outside the sectioning commands (`\section`, etc.).  Of course, package `hyperref` complains.  I do not want to scan the sectioning commands to put `\texorpdfstring` inside them.  I thought to change the definitions so my commands use `\texorpdfstring`.  In this case `\texorpdfstring` will appear outside the sectioning commands.  I wonder wheter this will work, or I need another solution.

Comment: `\texorpdfstring` is independently from the command `\section`. For more details please provide a MWE.

Comment: Did you try? :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\texorpdfstring` works outside of `\section`, I've used it several times to avoid issues with `\and` in `\author` (it's not rendered when filling the PDF metadata), and I don't get errors or warnings when I use it that way.

I think it's really just a one-liner to have an if-then-else branching instruction. I may be wrong, of course.